# Using Boole's Inequality to Prove Observation

Tags: probability, self-study

I'm walking through the book "Probability" by Jim Pitman book solo and cannot wrap my head around this problem;

Use Boole's Inequality and the fact that, [image]

to prove.

[image]

How do you approach this problem?

Comment: Hint: $1 \geq P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$ and so $P(A\cap B) \geq P(A)+P(B)-1$.

Comment: Which "Pitman book" is this? Please give a complete reference. It looks like you should probably add the `self-study` tag (and read its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info))